# C++ exception handling not working as expected

Tags: c++, exception

I'm trying to understand exception handling, and I'm testing this simple code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stdexcept>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector<int> v(4);
    try
    {
        v[v.size()] = 100;
    }
    catch(const exception& e){
        cerr << e.what() << endl;
    }
}
```

I expect the output to be something like:

> Out of Range error: vector::_M_range_check

However, I get the same error message as if I did this:

```
...
vector<int> v(4);
v[v.size()] = 100;
...
```

that is, the usual 'non-exception-aware' code.

My question is:
What is wrong with the try catch logic I'm implementing?

Comment: Try `v.at(v.size())`, I don't think the `operator[]` throws a `std::exception` object (it isn't required to by the standard).

Comment: That is correct. Note: On MSVC(12) operator[] will throw in debug mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are assuming that the type of exception thrown by the `std::vector<int>` member `operator[]` is derived from `std::exception`, this may not be the case as the standard does not specify that `operator[]` must perform range checking or throw an exception.

Try using the `at` member function instead for a range-checking function which throws a `std::out_of_range` object which derives from `std::exception`.

For example:

```
v.at( v.size() ) = 100;
```

Comment: Thank you both for the fast answer. I'd choose both as "the" answer if I could. I have a better undertsanding now. I wasn't aware that the function may or may not trhow an exception, and that this exception may or may not be a subclass of std::exception.

Answer (score 6):

Using the subscript operator `[]` to access vector elements does not do a range check - you get undefined behaviour if the index is out of range.

For checked access, use the `at` function instead:

```
v.at(v.size()) = 100;
```

If the check fails, this will throw `std::out_of_range`, a subclass of `std::exception`, which your code should catch.

Comment: Thank you both for the fast answer. I'd choose both as "the" answer if I could. I have a better undertsanding now. I wasn't aware that the function may or may not trhow an exception, and that this exception may or may not be a subclass of std::exception.

Comment: @MarcosModenesi: If you use `at`, then the exception is guaranteed to be a subclass of `std::exception` (specifically, `std::out_of_range`).